# what will happen if our String Memory is full in Java 8 in a real life application

Tags: java-8, string-pool

I am currently working on java 8 Project from last 4 years. In an interview, I was being asked what will happen if your String pool is full. Never encountered it. Already searched a lot didnt find any satisfactory answer for real life app.

Comment: Short answer - an `OutOfMemoryError`. You didn't specify whether there's a swarm of compile time string constants or strings are being repeatedly added to the pool using `intern()` at runtime?

Comment: string constants

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if String Pool runs out of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911800/what-happens-if-string-pool-runs-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1):

You should ask back what “String pool is full” is supposed to mean. The JVM’s runtime string pool is a hash table of *references* to objects, the string objects residing in the heap memory like every object.

There are two possibilities what the interviewer could have meant:

1. The number of strings exceeds the hash table’s size. This is an implementation specific issue. The widespread HotSpot JVM indeed has a fixed size table, however, it can deal with collisions, so only the performance will slightly degrade. This only affects calls of `intern()` or the first time execution of code containing a string constant, so you might never notice.
2. There is not enough memory to add a string. This is not different to other scenarios of not having enough memory. E.g. if the allocation of the `String` fails, it doesn’t matter whether there was the intention of adding it to the pool. The usual response is an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Answer (score 0):

You get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space from java 7 onwards . While java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in older version of java like 6.
[Related Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911800/what-happens-if-string-pool-runs-out-of-memory)